# cant get json data from url

Tags: jquery, json

i have the json data like:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 1,
    "data": {
        "6217895": {
            "clan": {
                "role_i18n": "Saha Komutanı",
                "clan_id": 16682,
                "role": "commander",
                "since": 1361201722
            },
            "achievements": {
                "tank_expert_uk": 0,
                "medal_dumitru": 3,
                "invader": 10,
                "medal_lehvaslaiho": 0,
                "warrior": 60,
                "medal_halonen": 1,
                "medal_pascucci": 6,
                "medal_orlik": 0,
                "medal_brothers_in_arms": 30,
                "mousebane": 0,
                "tank_expert_france": 0,
                "mechanic_engineer_ussr": 0,
                "medal_bruno_pietro": 0,
                "medal_delanglade": 1,
                "lucky_devil": 3,
                "defender": 39,
                "armor_piercer": 1,
                "medal_kay": 2,
                "supporter": 115,
                "mechanic_engineer": 0,
                "steelwall": 185,
                "max_sniper_series": 48,
                "medal_knispel": 1,
                "medal_boelter": 0,
                "medal_ekins": 1,
                "medal_heroes_of_rassenay": 0,
                "medal_tamada_yoshio": 0,
                "tank_expert_usa": 0,
                "mechanic_engineer_germany": 0,
                "max_piercing_series": 26,
                "tank_expert": 0,
                "iron_man": 4,
                "medal_radley_walters": 5,
                "kamikaze": 6,
                "tank_expert_germany": 0,
                "beasthunter": 8,
                "sniper": 429,
                "medal_tarczay": 0,
                "medal_lavrinenko": 2,
                "mechanic_engineer_france": 0,
                "medal_oskin": 0,
                "medal_burda": 0,
                "medal_billotte": 0,
                "huntsman": 0,
                "hand_of_death": 1,
                "medal_fadin": 0,
                "medal_lafayette_pool": 0,
                "max_killing_series": 7,
                "tank_expert_china": 0,
                "mechanic_engineer_usa": 0,
                "medal_kolobanov": 0,
                "patton_valley": 0,
                "bombardier": 1,
                "medal_abrams": 2,
                "max_invincible_series": 3,
                "medal_poppel": 2,
                "medal_crucial_contribution": 0,
                "raider": 1,
                "max_diehard_series": 9,
                "mechanic_engineer_uk": 0,
                "invincible": 0,
                "lumberjack": 0,
                "sturdy": 57,
                "title_sniper": 1,
                "sinai": 13,
                "diehard": 0,
                "medal_carius": 1,
                "medal_le_clerc": 2,
                "tank_expert_ussr": 0,
                "evileye": 11,
                "mechanic_engineer_china": 0,
                "medal_nikolas": 0,
                "scout": 24
            },
            "statistics": {
                "clan": {
                    "spotted": 0,
                    "hits": 13,
                    "battle_avg_xp": 716,
                    "draws": 1,
                    "wins": 1,
                    "losses": 0,
                    "capture_points": 0,
                    "battles": 2,
                    "damage_dealt": 2773,
                    "hits_percents": 76,
                    "damage_received": 2889,
                    "shots": 17,
                    "xp": 1432,
                    "frags": 1,
                    "survived_battles": 1,
                    "dropped_capture_points": 0
                },
                "all": {
                    "spotted": 13298,
                    "hits": 63481,
                    "battle_avg_xp": 572,
                    "draws": 124,
                    "wins": 5603,
                    "losses": 4587,
                    "capture_points": 15274,
                    "battles": 10314,
                    "damage_dealt": 11681437,
                    "hits_percents": 72,
                    "damage_received": 9508670,
                    "shots": 88151,
                    "xp": 5899761,
                    "frags": 10139,
                    "survived_battles": 2916,
                    "dropped_capture_points": 10477
                },
                "company": {
                    "spotted": 117,
                    "hits": 1565,
                    "battle_avg_xp": 722,
                    "draws": 2,
                    "wins": 166,
                    "losses": 87,
                    "capture_points": 588,
                    "battles": 255,
                    "damage_dealt": 347292,
                    "hits_percents": 79,
                    "damage_received": 250625,
                    "shots": 1977,
                    "xp": 184204,
                    "frags": 231,
                    "survived_battles": 125,
                    "dropped_capture_points": 436
                },
                "max_xp": 2566
            },
            "account_id": 6217895,
            "created_at": 1333888616,
            "updated_at": 1382372956,
            "private": null,
            "nickname": "lsvenom"
        }
    }
}
```

and my code is:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
        var nick=$('#username').val();
        if(nick.length > 0){ 
            var url='http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/account/list/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31&search='+nick;
            $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                $('#result').html('');
                $.each(json.data, function(index, data) {
                    if(index=='0'){
                        $('#result').append('<p> name: ' + data.nickname+ '</p>');
                        $('#result').append('<p> ID: ' +data.id+ '</p>');
                        var id=data.id;
                        var url2='http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/account/info/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31&account_id='+id;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: url2,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            success: function(stats) {
                                stats = JSON.parse(stats);
                                $.each(stats.data.id.statistics.all, function(i, all) {
                                   var wins=all.wins;
                                   var losses=all.losses;
                                   $('#result').append('<p>Wins: ' +wins+ '</p>');
                                   $('#result').append('<p>Losses: ' +losses+ '</p>');
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }else{ 
            alert('enter username');
        }
    });
```

the mistake is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'statistics' of undefined
$.ajax.success
c 
p.fireWith 
k
r
```

What im doing wrong here?

im newbie in getting json data, so please help me! Thank you all! :)

Comment: In "$.each(stats.data.id.statistics.all,", id is not defined?

Comment: `stats.data.statistics.all`

Comment: firstly i get id from nickname, then use it to get data

Comment: Will your JSON have multiple id's if there are many users?

Comment: If this is on a different server than your own, you'll need to use [JSON-P](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger it is open for CORS json

Comment: Can you tell me whether you will have multiple id's in your JSON? Since in one of the answers comment you said that it would work for one user only?

Comment: thank u everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` may be `dynamic` so try this,

```
  stats = JSON.parse(stats);
  $.each(stats.data, function(i, id){
       $(id.statistics.all).each(function(j,all){
            var wins=all.wins;
            var losses=all.losses;
            $('#result').append('<p>Wins: ' +wins+ '</p>');
            $('#result').append('<p>Losses: ' +losses+ '</p>');
        });
  });
```

Comment: yes this one is working! :) thank you very much! but with some changes, removed `stats = JSON.parse(stats);`

Answer (score 2):

did you check whether you should first parse it before using it as a json object?
like this;

```
stats = JSON.parse(stats);
$.each(stats.data.eval(id).statistics.all, function(i, all) {
   var wins=all.wins;
   var losses=all.losses;
   $('#result').append('<p>Wins: ' +wins+ '</p>');
   $('#result').append('<p>Losses: ' +losses+ '</p>');
});
```

Comment: There is no property called `id`

Comment: @Johan thsat's because there is no property called id, you have to use `6217895` explicitly

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the code, so u can understand how i use `id`

Comment: @venom try `eval(id)` instead of id and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You have no property `id`, you have to use `6217895` but that's not a valid property name so that json seems to be invalid.

The correct path would be `stats.data.6217895.statistics.all` but, as I said before, this is invalid and would throw an error.

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the code, so u can understand how i use `id`

Answer (score 1):

if there are multiple id's in single json then @Rohan Kumar code will work. If you will always get same json but with different id then this would work for you :)

```
stats = JSON.parse(stats);
$.each(stats.data[0].statistics.all, function(i, all) {
   var wins=all.wins;
   var losses=all.losses;
   $('#result').append('<p>Wins: ' +wins+ '</p>');
   $('#result').append('<p>Losses: ' +losses+ '</p>');
});
```